# Mysql: count record number belong caterory is string pattern

Tags: mysql

My record is belong to one or more caterory, and data is store in database:

(database struct)

id | caterory_ids

1    |3|6|7|

(record id 1, belong to 3 caterory id: 3, 6 and 7)

Now I need to count total record by caterory id in one mysql query..
Example:

(record result)
Caterory | Record_number

1        | 250

2        | 140

Please help me for mysql string query.

Comment: You should better change your table design. Never store multiple values in a single column! Use a new mapping table and a categories table

Comment: I haven't right to change database design, and now I must write sql-string for current design.

Comment: Good luck. I do not see how this is possible in an easy way.

Comment: Do you have another table that has just the category IDs themselves, as a column? Like a `categories` table, maybe?

Comment: @Amadan: Database haven't category table, caterory id number only store in sub-record together :(

Comment: Given the horribleness of the database design, is there any chance you can do this outside the database? This would be way easier in Ruby or PHP or whatever you're interfacing with MySQL...

Comment: @Amadan: Now, PHP foreach category id and count from database.

Ex: Select count(1) from job where category like '%|1|%'

And database have about 30 category of kind. So, PHP must foreach 30 times, and run 30 times mysql query.

So, I need to query by only 1 query string.

Comment: That's actually the fastest you can hope for without changing the DB.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose you made your Database

```
Cat_ID | Record_number | ID
1 | 250 | 1
2 | 140 | 2
3 | 160 | 2
4 | 190 | 3
5 | 135 | 1
```

and so on...

Comment: Hic, I haven't right to change database design, and now I must write sql-string for current design :(